# Why I can't access columns with spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on the following dataframe:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 54294 entries, 0 to 54293
Data columns (total 39 columns):
permalink               49438 non-null object
name                    49437 non-null object
homepage_url            45989 non-null object
category_list           45477 non-null object
 market                 45470 non-null object
 funding_total_usd      49438 non-null object
.....
```

Two columns, market and funding_total_usd, seem to have space at the front but when I type `df[' market']` or `df['market']`. I only get an error message like `KeyError: 'market'`

And I cannot rename them in which case I need to access them first to rename them.

Comment: You can always set & get the column names by `df.columns`.

Comment: You probably have _trailing_ spaces in addition to the _leading_ spaces. Consider cleaning the column names with `df.columns=[c.strip() for c in df.columns]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer but a way to solve it (as there are different types of white-space).

```
i = 0
for column in df.columns:
    print(str(i) + '-|' + column + '|')
    i += 1
```

Then you can see what is at the start and the end (maybe you are missing a whitespace there too. Then you can use the index `i`, to print out the column name character bytecode by character bytecode to see which character it is exactly.

Comment: @Cece What works? Using the index to find the column name, then use that to reference the column?

Comment: Welcome to SO,if answers work, you accept the answer as well. I'd like to edit the answer with the full solution though.